# type parameter extends and method parameter mismatch error

Tags: java, generics

I created something like below:

ConcreteObserver1 is the subclass of IObserver

Interfaces definitions:

```
public interface ISubject<T,O extends IObserver<T>> {

    public void addObserver(O observer);

    public void removeObserver(O observer);

    public void updateAllSubjects(T value);

}


 public interface IObserver<T> {

    public void update(T value);

}

public class ConcreteObserver1<T> implements IObserver<T> {
```

Concrete Subject class containing IObserver

```
public class ConcreteSubject<T, O extends IObserver<T>> implements
        ISubject<T,O> {

    public ConcreteSubject() {
        addObserver(new ConcreteObserver1<T>());
    }

    ConcurrentSkipListSet<O> observersList = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<O>();

    public void addObserver(O observer) {
        observersList.add(observer);
```

`addObserver(new ConcreteObserver1<T>());` not working.

**It complains as below**

The method addObserver(O) in the type ConcreteSubject is not applicable for the arguments (ConcreteObserver1)

Why ?

I told  `O extends IObserver<T>` in `ConcreteSubject` type parameter definition, which says O is a sub-type of IObserver which is ConcreteObserver1

Why it is complaining.

Comment: Why do you have a class inside an interface/

Comment: What's wrong in above code?

Comment: What is `ISubject`? What is inside `IObserver` and how can you write 1extends IObserver<T>` when `IObserver` is an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter `O` is defined to be a subtype of `IObserver<T>`, this is correct. But it may stand for **any** subtype. You don't say anywhere that it stands for `ConcreteObserver1`. It could also stand for `ConcreteObserver42` or something else.

From what you posted so far, it does not seem like you really have to define `O` as a type parameter of `ConcreteSubject`. You could specifically say that `ConcreteSubject` always uses a `ConcreteObserver1`. If this is not the case, you should probably explain your intention more clearly (and possibly, in a more readable form).

(Edited based on the comments)

```
interface ISubject<T,O extends IObserver<T>> 
{
    void addObserver(O observer);
    void removeObserver(O observer);
    void updateAllSubjects(T value);

}
interface IObserver<T> 
{
    void update(T value);
}

class ConcreteObserver1<T> implements IObserver<T> 
{
    @Override
    public void update(T value) {}
}
class ConcreteObserver2<T> implements IObserver<T>
{
    @Override
    public void update(T value) {}
}
class ConcreteObserver3<T> implements IObserver<T>
{
    @Override
    public void update(T value) {}
}


class ConcreteSubject<T> implements ISubject<T,IObserver<T>>
{
    ConcurrentSkipListSet<IObserver<T>> observersList =
        new ConcurrentSkipListSet<IObserver<T>>();

    public ConcreteSubject()
    {
        addObserver(new ConcreteObserver1<T>());
        addObserver(new ConcreteObserver2<T>());
        addObserver(new ConcreteObserver3<T>());
    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        observersList.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        observersList.remove(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAllSubjects(T value)
    {
        for (IObserver<T> observer : observersList)
        {
            observer.update(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My intention I had ConcreteObserver1,2,3...So, I want to use the addObserver method which can take any ConcreteObserver1,2,3...As your case If I want to call with argument like this addObserver(new ConcreteObserver2<T>());, how shall I do.Your point holds good for  ConcurrentSkipListSet<O> observersList = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<O>(); because I don't know which ConcreteObserver I'm putting but why parameter signature (O observer) cannot hold objects of ConcreteObserver types.

Comment: Hi marco I want to ask another thing from your answer what does this mean class ConcreteSubject<T> implements ISubject<T,ConcreteObserver1<T>> in interface definition you say it holds 2 types of objects one of type T and another ConcreteObserver1<T> and in class type parameter definition you said only ConcreteSubject<T> why so. Is there any reason to this. I mean why not this way is there any difference. ConcreteSubject<T,ConcreteObserver1<T>> implements ISubject<T,ConcreteObserver1<T>>. I want to learn how to define inteface generic types and concrete class generic types.

Comment: @bhadram Then read the [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: @bhadram Added an EDIT

Comment: @Marco Thank you very Now I'm very clear. I understood the concepts of generics. Now I think I'm learning some practicalities.Thank you very much.